# Android google map2 has gone blank

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I've copied ans pasted coding from following link [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map) but I render this following coding at my phone then google map has gone blank as per attachment. Please let me know why building, streets and others cannot display there.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you enabled googple maps for android in the map api console?

Comment: which key you are using debug or sign?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yap, I've already enabled google maps in API console.

Comment: @mukesh I've used signing key.

Comment: if you are using debug key then map show blank if you install app by apk.if you using sign key(using app keystore) & you install by eclipse then it also show blank

Comment: @ppshein: just post your google map code..

Comment: @ppshein then you have to install app using apk in device, then map show.

Comment: I did it your option two "if you using sign key(using app keystore) & you install by eclipse then it also show blank". Then how can I do?

Comment: create apk of app & insert into sd card .Go in sd card & click for install.

Comment: @mukesh I've added app coding.

Comment: @ppshein there is no problem in your code.if any error exists then map not show even blank.Had you created apk of your app?

Comment: @mukesh I've created apk and install into phone. Unfortunately, nothing changed. :(

Comment: @ppshein check your  key.Something going wrong while creating google map key.

Comment: API is generated by google api console. That's why.

Comment: @ppshein yes.but check sha key & package name(which is manifest) is correct while creating key for android.

Comment: @mukesh can you write the last comment as answers? then I mark as correct answer after that.

Comment: @ppshein is problem solve?

Comment: yap.. now.. map come up.. Thanks for "check sha key & package name(which is manifest) is correct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check SHA-1 fingerprint key & package name(which is manifest) is correct while creating google map key for android.[read link title- Obtaining an api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key)

Answer (score 1):

May be you haven't set Google maps api key in manifest.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Set your (debug/prod depending upon your proj) api key by replacing API_KEY.

Comment: nope.. I've already configured google map API key in manifest.

Comment: @ppshein. problem is with the api key, or else at least you will see grids on your map.

Comment: I've created API key from Google API console.